# Best Practices for Working with Multiple Monitors in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Now that Visual Studio 2010 has support for multiple monitors, I am curious how other people have their environments arranged. I have yet to come up with an arrangement that I am really satisfied with.

The current best I have come up with for my 2 monitor system is to have all code windows detached. Then, on my primary monitor, I am able to have two code windows side by side (using the Windows 7 keyboard shortcuts WinKey+LeftArrow and WinKey+RightArrow.) On my secondary monitor I put the rest of the IDE with all of the tool windows that are normally on the bottom (errors list, find window, call stack, etc...) docked where the code windows normally go. I've also tried having all those things detached and having almost nothing in the IDE proper.

The problems with this layout are:

- Newly opened code windows always open in the IDE, not on top of one of the detached windows.
- Detached code windows do not remember their exact placement from session to session (they are slightly off, having me to use the winkey + arrow key shortcut again and again for each window.
- There seems to be no way to have the code panes aware that they are on top of one another (IE -- multiple tabs.)
- The CTRL+TAB shortcut always displays on top of the IDE proper.
- The Code Panes are always "on top" of (children of) the IDE. So clicking on any code pane brings the IDE to the foreground, even when I care only about that code pane, and not the IDE.
- Other more minor issues...

What would go a long way to making this better is having the code panes detach such that they are tab strips that can have other code panes docked within them.

The new multi-monitor support in VS2010 is good, but it still seems really lacking.

Can these issues be solved with an add-in? If so, is anyone aware of one?

Is there a better way to work with the IDE on multiple monitors than what I am doing?

NOTE: While this question is subjective (there is certainly no "this is the best way and that's final" answer) I'd really like to know possibly better methods of working with the IDE than what I have come up with. The intent is not to start a "mine's best" flame war.

Comment: I've had a related issue with my multi-monitor (2x2) setup. Basically, I have my tools detached and floating on other screens (IDE maxed with main code windows at bottom right, Solution Explorer floating left, output  floating above it.) When I build/run my prog and return from it, the two floating panes jump back right on top and in the middle of my IDE window. Wonder if anyone knows what to do about that?

Comment: @Carlos: I don't have experience with the setup you use, but the IDE does use individual configurations for debugging and editing and saves their state individually, too. So it jumps back to the "editing view" when you stop debugging, but it should jump back to where you left it when you switched from editing to debugging by starting your program. Does this make any sense?

Comment: @sbi: Yes, I thought it was meant to do that. But it seems to not remember where my toolboxes are supposed to be, and dumps them right in the middle each time I return from a debug session. Could it be to do with my display drivers?

Comment: @Carlos: I wouldn't know. You might want to contact MS support about this.

Comment: @Carlos first try Windows->Reset Window Layout then install perspectives plugin, see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931808/best-practices-for-working-with-multiple-monitors-in-visual-studio-2010/13415328#13415328 this fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 6):

I'm late to this question, and VS2012 has been out for a while now, but there are Microsoft's [Visual Studio Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef), which include the Document Tab Well.  It lets you group tabs, put multiple tabs in each floating window, float windows by default, and so on.

In [VS2012's power tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3a96a4dc-ba9c-4589-92c5-640e07332afd), it appears to be called "Custom Document Well", but seems to have the same type of functionality.

Answer (score 5):

I always have my IDE on the right monitor, with all the editor windows and tools there. That leaves the left monitor for the programs to debug, my email client, wasting time on SO, and other stuff. You can have editor windows side-by-side even in older versions of VS by using vertical tab groups. This still works in VS2010 and allows you to rearrange them by dragging them between tab groups.

Sometimes I put the output and stack windows on the left monitor, below the debugged program, in order to have more screen real estate for looking at the code.

Comment: -1 Offtopic; the OP asked how to use multiple monitors in VS2k10

Comment: @Rising Star - Seems a bit harsh, rather then negating it comment it.

Comment: @Rising - from the OP "I am curious how other people have their environments arranged."  sbi has answered this exactly.

Comment: I don't mean to come off as harsh.  I simply have experience that I've asked questions on SO and seen something peripherally related to what I'm asking posted as an answer.  After several such posts, I have several "answers" and still have no idea what the solution to the problem I'm asking about is.  When I read this answer, I felt that it does little to answer the question of what is a good way to work with multiple monitors in VS2k10.  My downvote is not meant to be a personal attack.

Comment: Well, looking back, I can now see that you mention that the feature of vs2k8 that your used before works the same in vs2k10.  However, when I click to reverse my vote, it says that I it's too late to change the vote unless the answer is edited.

Comment: Often I want to see code from different parts of the same file on each monitor, eg, when tracing calls within a class, or see several snippets of code, such as a SQL view, a couple procedures, etc. For this I have my favourite text editor in my second monitor and just copy over scraps as necessary. (I guess you could even have another copy of Vis Studio open.) Realize this isn't strictly within the scope of the question but has been handy for me, including on VS 2012.

Answer (score 3):

I have a 3 monitor setup, I've found it just doesn't quite work for me with 2.  I have one center larger monitor in normal landscape mode and I keep the side monitors in portrait mode.

On the center monitor, I keep the IDE with either one or two panes of code windows.  I also still keep the output and watch windows on the bottom below the code windows.

On my left monitor I place the navigation windows, like the solution explorer and my visual assist tool windows.

On the right monitor I keep threads / call stack or the new parallel stacks windows and my mail / browser / documentation windows.

Answer (score 2):

### Perspectives

http://perspectives.codeplex.com

> Perspectives allows Visual Studio 2010 and 2012 users to select and
>   manager Visual Studio windows configurations. This works much the same
>   as perspectives in Eclipse.

**Features**

- View available perspectives
- Apply perspectives
- Add new perspectives
- Update perspectives
- Delete perspectives

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used VS2010 yet, but what I like to do a lot with VS2008 as well as many other IDEs is actually expand the entire IDE to cover both monitors(I have my monitors side by side).

When looking at related files(.aspx and .aspx.cs) it's nice to see as much of the code as possible, so I like to allow each file to have their own screen.

On the other hand, when working with something like Illustrator or Photoshop it's nice to have all the tools and views on another screen so you can focus on your layout.